# Terrain from contour where higher zone "overlaps" lower one, on Sketchup

Tags: sketchup

In Sketchup, there is a way to create a terrain from contours. However, there are some cases where a part of the map at a higher altitude, covers a lower part of the terrain itself. Imagine the case of overhanging cliffs or caves.

Is there way to create a terrain, or a mesh from a contour that present this sort of features?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to divide the terrain to non-overlapping surfaces that are created separately and finally moved to their final places. You can form closed surfaces (=so called solids) by intersecting the surfaces, exploding the groups and deleting the exessive surface areas.

That's quite complex. In paid version you can make boolean operations (union, intersection, subtract) that are useful to combine solids. You can make your cave by subtracting.